# Is there an excel formula that returns data from another cell if first cell has data?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to write an equation that will check if cell A2 has data it will populate cell B2 with data from D2 but will remain blank if cell A2 has no data. Here is my example. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: `=IF(A2="","",D2)`?

Comment: Look into `IF`-function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

Comment: @scott. You're right. Writing an actual answer is faster then referring to the documentation.

Comment: @scott, I thought that would work but it returns nothing when D2 has data

Comment: Got it to work! Thank you!! @Scott I think there was an issue with many embedded equations.

Comment: @P.b for me, if I take the time to find the documentation I would write up a true answer.  I tend to comment-answer when I do not have the time or the motivation to do a true answer.

Answer (score -2):

Put this in B2:
`=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",D2)`

Since I dont have enough "reputation" to comment; I'll comment here: The above formula by Scott works but not always. The test condition "" means empty, but not null. The ISBLANK() test makes sure it works.

Comment: That is not true. `""` works whether the cell is truly blank or contains an empty string from a formula.  ISBLANK will only work if the cell is truly blank, no formula that returns an `""`